# The token is not showing

Tags: solidity

I have been creating a smart contract on binance testnet and it was compiled successfully, after deployment I wont find any token created, even if I add the contract address to metamask it will show nothing. I notice that when I tried to compile, from the drop down menu it doesn't created actual contract writing on the code. when I try to change it to actual contract from drop down menu I will get this below error.

Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }

Comment: Please edit your question and show the contract source code.

Comment: I have tried to paste the code but they are to large to be accepted on stack over. I don't  think the code has error because I have copied smart contract code from about 5 sources they all behave identical way. could be it that remix is having issue? all the code deployed successfully but the transaction hash is empty and bnb gas fee in metamask is low as well. i changed the contract from drop down its still the same.

Comment: Then paste only the relevant parts - constructor of the contract you're trying to deploy, and dependencies of the constructor (e.g. interface definitions if the constructor defines some interface, etc.)

Comment: I did something now, I had been creating the smart contract with binance testnet and i decided to try it with mainet it works...Its show actual bnb charges but on testnet the bnb charges was vey low knowing the transation hash will be empty. i dont just know what could have wrong with testnet. I knew that there is no problem with code.